# Difficult Child <> Parent <> Child (sibling) SQL Query with Rails & Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `trailers` table. A Trailer belongs_to a Movie. A Movie has_many Notifications. A Trailer has_many Notifications `:through` Movies.

I want to order the Trailers by the number of their notifications. I've tried a few different queries (that haven't worked) and I feel like I'm overcomplicating it.

Can someone help start me off?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up landing on:

```
Trailer.joins(:movie => :notifications).
          select('trailers.*, COUNT(notifications.id) AS notifications_count').
          joins(:movie).group('trailers.id').
          order('notifications_count DESC')
```